# Rails 3: preventing Users from voting on their own content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using Devise and CanCan to setup authentication and authorization in my app. Now I'm building a Like system that allows users to like/dislike a given model. What is the best way to prevent users from voting on their own content?

Right now I'm checking in the Controller if the content owner is equal to the current user, but it seems to me that this logic should be on the Ability model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in using cancan, but maybe you can use block like this:

```
can :like, Product do |product|
  product.try(:owner) != user
end
```

Comment: Igor, I think this is the idea. I've the create action for Like, but I'm not sure how I can combine it with the Product in your example. The ability that I've now is:

    `can :create, Like
    can :update, Like do |like|
      like.try(:user) == user
    end`

Answer (score 0):

In your ability.rb you need to do something like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
      ...
      can :like, Product, :user_id => user.id
      ...
  end
end
```

and then in the controller:

```
@product.like if can? :like, @product
```

also in your view you can then hide the like button:

```
<% if can? :like, @product%>
  <%= link_to "Like", like_product_path(@product) %>
<% end %>
```